# Choosing the best fit sentence to mail prospective PhD supervisor

Tags: phd, application, professorship, email, communication

I am applying for a PhD scholarship which was posted on the university website and for that, I am writing mail to the professor. I have written about my background, academics, interests and experience. I want to ask him the procedure for applying for the scholarship. I am not a native English speaker so I am not sure that which of the following sentence would be best for that:

`Plese let me know about the application procedure`

`Please let me know how can I apply for the position`

Or if there is another way to ask, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording probably doesn't matter too much. You can simply say "I am interested in applying for X scholarship. How does the application procedure work?".

However, before you send the email, make sure you check the details aren't already online somewhere. Also consider if your email would be better addressed to the department administrator rather than the professor, as an administrator is more likely to know all the necessary technical details.